# Creating customisable product block (change appearance on user selections)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a web app where users can customize on real-time their bags using the available options.

[image: bag customization js]

Firstly I thought in having an image per every combination but that's not very intelligent due to the huge amount of possible combinations.

Another idea is to crop every customizable bag section and create a version for every option. This is better but not ideal. The idea is to be able to simply upload new options, without needing to be cropping images every time.

How would you do this guy?

I have some javascript experience but this is the first time when I do something like this.

Many thanks!

Comment: If I were to do it, I would layer each element of the bag as PNG's on top of one another; which would require cropping/manipulation, but I don't think you can get around that. You could also use a [HTML5 Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) if you're feeling particularly adventurous.
It's not jQuery, but you could look into PHP's [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension, which you could use to generate an actual flattened image of the bag on the server-side.

Comment: I'd personally get the bag as a SVG and play around with it using SVG patterns, properties & CSS.

Comment: Thanks, SVG would be a good option but I'm forced to work with traditional images. At this point probably, the most efficient is to work with PNG's as James suggests. I like the adventure but I have limited time.